# Ubuntu 12.04 Touchscreen Calibration

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 installed, with dual monitor, via VGA and DVI Interface. The monitor is one touch screen and the other one is regular LCD Monitor.

The touch screen is made in China with some unknown brand, and I am using eGalax Driver. The touch screen is now detected and works, but i need to do some calibration since it does not correctly perform click on touch.

The problem is, when I’m using xinput_calibrator, it shows 4 crosses to be clicked on, because I’m using dual monitor, the crosses is now show 2 on the touch screen (touchable) and the others on the other monitor which is regular non-touch monitor.

Please help, thank you.

====TRIED THIS, NO LUCK=========

i tried to unplug the second monitor and then redo the calibration with xinput_calibration, and then saved it. Restart, all accuracy is fine, and the touch screen is working perfectly. BUT when then the 2nd monitor (Samsung LCD TV, via HDMI) is replugged, the touchscreen calibration was simply like gone, the accuracy is now lost. Touch on a point, the system click on another.

My screens was configured at 1024x768 on both monitor. With touchscreen on the left. System (Ubuntu 12.04 x64) sees it as big 2048x768 resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem, using [Coordinate Transformation Matrix](http://www.x.org/wiki/XInputSpec/). Well yes, I need to pull off the second (non touchable) monitor and run xinput_calibrator. With the calibration number resulted from that, I'm applying the matrix and plug in the second monitor. Everything runs well.

Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pull off the second monitor, do the calibration using `xinput_calibrator` and then replug the second monitor.

Comment: tried this, please refer to my comment above. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove your second monitor , Then do the calibration with your program labeled xinput , After you calibrate , Plug in your second moniter and your worries are gone and everything is done

Hope I helped

Comment: Hi, i've tried that. The calibration is now able to done. And calibrated fine. 

BUT, when the 2nd monitor replugged, the calibration was simply like gone. I touch on a point, the cursor move to another point, NOT accurate at all (it was accurate on single touch monitor).

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

- Use "xinput map-to-output  " to map your input device to output device.
- Using xinput --list to list your input device id.
- Use xrandr to list your output device name.